# DataGridView showing wrong time from DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I'm trying to get a date from a DateTimePicker, and a time from another DateTimePicker, and show them both at a DataGridView which is bound to a List. I'm getting the dates well and both data are well-inputted (I displayed a messageBox and it seems to be getting both date and time well). But, the thing is, for some reason, the time in the DataGridView is always showing as 00:00 (the first minute from the date picked). Here's my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{

    private List<DateTime> dates;
    private BindingList<DateTime> bDates;
    private BindingSource dSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        dates = new List<DateTime>();
        dtpDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dtpDate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        dtpTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dtpTime.CustomFormat = "hh:mm";
        dtpTime.ShowUpDown = true;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime input = dtpDate.Value.Date + dtpTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
        MessageBox.Show(input.toString()); //This shows the date correctly
        dates.Add(input);
        bDates = new BindingList<DateTime>(dates);
        dSource = new BindingSource(bDates, null);
        grid.DataSource = dSource;
        grid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
    }

}
```

The DateTime type at the DataGridView shows another 12 columns, which I chose to hide; some could've been useful, because there was one for minutes and another one for hours, but I preferred to just make one by myself and show it. **How could I show the time properly and not always 00:00?**

EDIT: Code snippet updated

Comment: This isn't enough code.  If those are your declarations in the *constructor*, then those variables would be local to only that block, and they wouldn't be available in the click event.  Post all the code that duplicates the problem.  I don't get 00:00.

Comment: Oh, alright then, i tried to simplify the code because it has a lot of validations, but i'll update it now. By 00:00 I mean it's the time being displayed at the DataGridView, like if it would refer to the initial time of the date picked; or do you mean you ran it and didn't get "00:00" as time?

Comment: I don't get "00:00" as the time.  I get `11:23:36.8013427` since I just ran it.

Comment: Oh, I thought we were looking at the TimeOfDay column.

Comment: Nope! I want to get a single column which shows that "input" I put onto the list, so I can look at all the dates and times I've put into the DataGridView; each row should be a dd/MM/yyyy hh:MM, but all the "hh:mm" look like "00:00"

Comment: It works when the DataSource is a DataTable.  If you want to use the List<>, you might have to use a CellFormatting event.

Comment: Ohh OK then. The thing is I'm doing some validations over all the dates inputted, so that was the main reason I was using the List<DateTime>; I guess using the DataTable would be a little bit harder to scan and, for example, look for an already registered date on it, right? I guess I'll keep the List and use some useful columns of the DataGridView I found (like the Hour and Minutes ones)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a `string` column in the grid for this.

I am confident the problem is coming from the `List<DateTime>` … When you use a `List<T>` as a `DataSource` to the grid (top grid), the grid will use each (non-collection) “property” in `T` as a column in the grid. This can be seen in the top grid. Using `DateTime` as `T`, will have “Date” as column 0, “Day” as column 1, “DayOfWeek” as column 2… etc. There will be a column for “hours”, “minutes” and seconds. (See picture).

[image]

I am guessing the problem could be due to the fact that the first “property” in the `DateTime` object is a `DateTime` object called “Date”, however, this “Date” `DateTime` object has its “Time” set to 12:00 A.M. Hence, the line of code `grid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";` … will always display this time value 00:00 representing 12:00 A.M. The “time” values we are looking for are from “this” `DateTime` object which are held in its Hours, Minutes and Seconds properties. These property values are in the other columns.

With that said, I suggest you try and use a `DataTable` with a `DateTime` column instead of a `List<DateTime>`. (bottom grid) This should not only solve the current issue, but it should make things a little easier. First a global `DataTable` variable `dataTable` is added to the code, and a second grid is added to the form to use the new data table. The `DateTime` column for this table is added in the `Form1_Load` event. In the button click event the same “input” variable used for the `List` is added to the `dataTable` rows. The second grids data source is set to the `dataTable`, then finally the grids first column format is set. I hope this makes sense.

```
private List<DateTime> dates;
private BindingList<DateTime> bDates;
private BindingSource dSource;

private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dates = new List<DateTime>();
  dtpDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  dtpDate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
  dtpTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  dtpTime.CustomFormat = "hh:mm";
  dtpTime.ShowUpDown = true;

  dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DateTime input = dtpDate.Value.Date + dtpTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
  MessageBox.Show(input.ToString()); //This shows the date correctly
  dates.Add(input);
  bDates = new BindingList<DateTime>(dates);
  dSource = new BindingSource(bDates, null);
  grid.DataSource = dSource;
  grid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";

  // using datatable on second grid
  dataTable.Rows.Add(input);
  grid2.DataSource = dataTable;
  grid2.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
}
```